# Copy workbook & paste into new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to open a workbook `FName` from a folder and copy a range from it and paste into a new workbook `WBNew`, but i keep getting error

> Subscript out of range or 1004 - Application defined

error.

Any idea why ?

```
Sub NewNumbers()

Dim FName As Workbook, WBNew As Workbook

Set FName = Workbooks.Open(Range("C3") & "\" & Range("C2"))
Set WBNew = Workbooks.Add

FName.Worksheets("Numbers").Range("U2", Range("U2").End(xlToRight)).Copy    
WBNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy >> Paste is a 1-line Command, also define a `Range` in `"Sheet1"` to paste.

```
Dim NumbersSht As Worksheet

' set the copied sheet object
Set NumbersSht = FName.Worksheets("Numbers")

With NumbersSht
    .Range("U2", .Range("U2").End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=WBNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")  '<--- Modify "A1" to your desired range
End With
```

Comment: When i try this i get "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".  (?)

Comment: @user9685718 when you run in **Debug** mode, at what line do you get this error ?

Comment: it happens at the line "FName.Worksheets("Numbers").Range("U2", Range("U2").End(xlToRight)).Copy _    
Destination:= WBNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")"

Comment: @user9685718 try now, let me know if you are getting an error, at what line

Comment: i get the same error but at 'FName.Worksheets("Numbers").Range("U2", Range("U2").End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=WBNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")'

Comment: @user9685718 are you sure you have "Numbers" sheet , and you have data on "U2" and to the right, like "V2", or "Y2" ?

Comment: Thanks! It works now! i ran it as this: Sub NewNumbers()

Dim FName As Workbook, WBNew As Workbook
Dim NumbersSht As Worksheet

Set FName = Workbooks.Open(Range("C3") & "\" & Range("C2"))
Set WBNew = Workbooks.Add
Set NumbersSht = FName.Worksheets("Numbers")

With NumbersSht
    .Range("U2", .Range("U2").End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=WBNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")  '<--- Modify "A1" to your desired range
End With


End Sub...  but when i try to run it a 2nd time, it gives the 1004 error. any idea why?